# Typescript Http.Post or Fetch in Express.js app

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, request, fetch

I'm new at Typescript and I'm trying to make an OAuth2 service like I've done in an Express.js normal app. But I'm not able to make a simple POST request with Typescript.

All the examples I've found say I have to use "fetch", but when I do it I get an error saying `fetch is not defined`.

My code:

```
app.get('/oauth/redirect', (req, res, next) =>  {
    let authCode:any = req.query.code;
    let view:string;

    if (authCode) {
        fetch(`${host_url}?client_id=${client_id}&client_secret=${client_secret}&code=${authCode}`, {method: 'POST'})
          .then((response) => {
            console.log('then!');
            console.log(response);
            accessToken = response.statusText;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('catch!');
            console.error(error);
        });

        view = 'explore';
    } else {
        view = 'error';
    }

    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/views/${view}.html`);
});
```

I'm using:

```
NodeJS: 12.18.3
Express: 4.17.1
TypeScript: 3.9.7
@types/express: 4.17.7
```

**UPDATE**

My `package.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Typscript test",
    "main": "app.js",
    "scripts": {
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn ./app/app.ts",
        "prod": "tsc && node ./build/app.js"
    },
    "author": "Andres Marotta",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/express": "^4.17.7",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.54",
        "typescript": "^3.9.7"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^14.0.26",
        "@types/node-fetch": "^2.5.7"
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here's my `tsconfig.json` file. It's the default created by Typescript, I removed the comments and added `"resolveJsonModule": true`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "strict": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you installed types definition for `node-fetch` and import it?

Comment: I've did it, but it says `Cannot find module 'node-fetch'`.

Comment: Check my answer, have you installed the type definition with `npm i -D @types/node-fetch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**fetch** is only available in the browser. Try to use **node-fetch**, **axios** or **node-request**.

Comment: I've installed `node-fetch` but it says it can't find it when I do the import.

Comment: it must be an issue with the global object. [see here](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#loading-and-configuring-the-module)



    const fetch = require('node-fetch');
    
    if (!globalThis.fetch) {
        globalThis.fetch = fetch;
    }

Comment: It doesn't work, :(. It says that `globalThis.fetch` is not the same type that imported `fetch`.

Comment: In this case, I suggest you change to axios, which is very easy to use and provides its own type definitions.

Comment: Axios works fine! Even thought I would like not to use libraries, it was the only way it would work. Thanks!

Comment: if you want to look for a solution with no libraries, you should look to http/https module of nodejs [https module](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) [http module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)

Comment: Been there, didn't work. The request returned "socket hang up" every time.